# Использовать numpy для изображений в matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

У меня есть изображение в `numpy` массиве, формат rgb. Как мне отобразить его с помощью `matplotlib`?

Вроде это верно, но при запуске в приложении `pydroid 3` (ос - Андроид) это не работает:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype="uint8")  # или "float32"
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Возможно, интерпретатор на Андроиде работает некорректно, т.к. ошибок нет, но и изображения нет

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас "на Андроиде" установлены библиотеки numpy и matplotlib? я вот сильно сомневаюсь.

Comment: Конечно, можете попробовать скачать "pydroid 3" во вкладке pip можете установить эти библиотеки и попробовать запустить код. Ошибок не будет, но и ничего не отображается.

Comment: `plt.show()` - пробовали добавлять в код после `imshow`?

Comment: Как очистить экран после изображения, чтобы можно было нарисовать график?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то у вас тут есть ошибка:

```
TypeError: data type 'unit8' not understood
```

Правильно будет:

```
img = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype="uint8")
                                      ^^
```

Т.е. `uint8`, а не `unit8`.

Comment: Да, в вопросе была опечатка, я её исправил. Суть от этого мало меняется, т.к. при исправлении всё ещё не появляется окно matplotlib.

Comment: Проблема, вернее всего, в использовании `pydroid 3`